# Run Java project (built in eclipse) using Batch File

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I want to run my **java project** which i've built using **Eclipse IDE**. Now my goal is to create a **batch file** which will **execute my project** with one click. i referred [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277965/create-batch-file-to-run-java-program) , but didn't get any idea. Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What didn't you understand from the answer to the question in the link?

Comment: create one jar file of your project and the a bat file with the command java -jar yourjar.jar

Comment: because there are .java file and .class file in eclipse work space. i aint sure which i should mention while creating .bat

Comment: Create a jar using eclipse or somehing. and use that.

Comment: @tejas . created jar file with .java  and classpath files. now when i double click jar file, it shows **invalid or corrupted file** error. are those 2 files enough to create jar OR should i include more files??

Comment: why do you want to double click your jar file? But anyway if it shows you invalid or corrupted file then you must have done it wrong. You can't just take some .class files and .java files and bundle them into a jar. It doesn't work that way. Take a look at tutorials for creating jars through eclipse projects of something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are working in eclipse, this makes things easier. First, export the whole program as a executable jar. You can do this by going to Files>Export and then in the pop up go to Java>Runnable Jar. Then follow the steps required to make it. Next you make a .bat file and write the following code.
`start javaw -jar NameOfJar.jar`
Make sure that you put the file in the same directory as your jar. Now you should be able and click on the .bat and execute the program!

Comment: created .bat file.. when i click it to run my jar, a cmd window opens and gets closed automatically

Comment: yeah, a batch file is really just a command prompt command, so the window will always open, no matter what you do. If you don't want the window then you will need to use a executable wrapper

Answer (score 3):

1.Open Notepad & write

```
@echo off

javac YOUR_JAVA_FILENAME.java

java YOUR_JAVA_FILENAME
```

2.Save-As executeJavaProgram.bat

Make sure that YOUR_JAVA_FILENAME.java resides with your batch file and java path is set in environment variable.

3 . Double click on batch file.

Comment: Please make sure that the classname.java is in same folder where .bat file exist.

Comment: created .bat file.. when i click it to run my jar, a cmd window opens and gets closed automatically

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) to create a jar file of your eclipse project.
After doing it create a batch file in the same folder where you exported the jar with the command: `java -jar yourjar.jar`

Comment: created jar file with .java  and classpath files. now when i double click jar file, it shows **invalid or corrupted file** error. are those 2 files enough to create jar OR should i include more files??

Comment: sis you follow the tutorial to generate the jar?

Answer (score 1):

Create jar file using eclipse i.e right click on your project select export jar file then provide file name to store your jar file. In this file eclipse will keep all .class file only and in META-INF folder main class definition if your are creating executable jar file.

Comment: created jar file with .java  and classpath files. now when i double click jar file, it shows **invalid or corrupted file** error. are those 2 files enough to create jar OR should i include more files??

Comment: created .bat file.. when i click it to run my jar, a cmd window opens and gets closed automatically